# Как получить список тегов на одном уровне

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, pcre

К примеру, есть кусок html:

```
<div>
  div text
  <div>div text</div>
</div>
outer text 1
<p>p text</p>
outer text 2
```

Существует ли возможность, получить все теги первого уровня вместе с содержимым? т.е. чтобы получилось:

```
<div>
  div text
  <div>div text</div>
</div>
<p>p text</p>
```

Comment: задача в том. чтобы сделать это, или сделать именно с регулярками?

Comment: @teran Да. Я тут упростил, на самом деле у меня не html или xml, а более специфичный формат документа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Формат неизвестен, задача непонятна. такой же и ответ. эта регулярка ищет что-то похожее на то, о чем вы спрашиваете, но совершенно безответственно

```
<\w+[^>]*?>((?R)|[^<]+)*<\/\w+>
```

[**посмотрите тут**](https://regex101.com/r/FhvOy1/1/)

Comment: Спасибо! Это то что нужно было - наводка. Далее, я уже сам доработаю под свои нужды